# How to show unique key exception before saving into database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I've created a gridview in which user can enter items and their quantities. The number of items are unknown so the requirement was that to able to add as much items the users want to. So I've given a provision to add item row for another entry. All these data entered gets into a temporary table and one all done by click on a button all these datas will save onto database.

Is there any way to hide the items which has been already selected on the previous row or show an error that the item has been already enter while selecting the dropdown value, before clicking on the button.

My gridview looks something like this:

[image]

gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItemList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" CssClass="newStyle9" ForeColor="Black" OnRowDataBound="gvItemList_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gvItemList_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="True" style="text-align: center" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No" SortExpression="Id">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="txtUnit" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Height="27px" Width="73px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="AddRowButton" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" Text="Add New Item" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void SetInitialRowToGrid()
    {
        // Initialize and Set initial row of Datatable
        var tempDataTable = new DataTable();
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("lblId");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("ddlItem");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtUnit");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtQty");        
        tempDataTable.Rows.Add("1", "", "", "");

        // Store that datatable into viewstate
        ViewState["TempTable"] = tempDataTable;

        // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable        
        gvItemList.DataSource = tempDataTable;
        gvItemList.DataBind();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            // Get TempTable from viewstate
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];
            DataRow tempRow = null;

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Get Grid's values
                    var Item =
                        (DropDownList)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItem");
                    var Unit =
                        (Label)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnit");
                    var Qty =
                        (TextBox)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQty");


                    // Create new row and update Row Number
                    tempRow = tempTable.NewRow();

                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["ddlItem"] = Item.SelectedValue;
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtUnit"] = Unit.Text;
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtQty"] = Qty.Text;                    
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                // Add data to datatable and viewstate
                tempTable.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                ViewState["TempTable"] = tempTable;

                // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
                gvItemList.DataSource = tempTable;
                gvItemList.DataBind();
            }
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }

    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var Item =
                        (DropDownList)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItem");
                    var Unit =
                        (Label)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnit");
                    var Qty =
                        (TextBox)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQty");


                    Item.SelectedValue = tempTable.Rows[i]["ddlItem"].ToString();
                    Unit.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["txtUnit"].ToString();
                    Qty.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["txtQty"].ToString();                   

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
    protected void gvItemList_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);

        deleteRow(index);
        SetPreviousData();        

        if (gvItemList.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            SetInitialRowToGrid();
        }
    }
    private int deleteRow(int index)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            // Get TempTable from viewstate
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];


            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Get Grid's TextBox values
                    var Item =
                        (DropDownList)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItem");
                    var Unit =
                        (Label)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnit");
                    var Qty =
                        (TextBox)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQty");
                }

                // Add data to datatable and viewstate                
                tempTable.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
                ViewState["TempTable"] = tempTable;

                // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
                gvItemList.DataSource = tempTable;
                gvItemList.DataBind();
            }
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks        
        return index;
    }

    protected void gvItemList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlItem = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlItem") as DropDownList);
            Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_ItemTableAdapter item;
            item = new Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_ItemTableAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = item.GetItems();

            ddlItem.DataSource = dt;
            ddlItem.DataTextField = "Item";
            ddlItem.DataValueField = "Item";
            ddlItem.DataBind();
            ddlItem.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Select an Item--", "0"));
        }
    }
    private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_Jr_BOMTableAdapter ds;
        ds = new Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_Jr_BOMTableAdapter();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        string[] splitItems = null;
        string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;

        try
        {
            foreach (string item in sc)
            {


                if (item.Contains(",,,"))
                {
                    //To prevent null reference error
                }
                else
                {
                    splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                    ds.InsertJrBOM(ddlState.SelectedValue, ddlDistrict.SelectedValue, ddlCluster.SelectedValue, ddlSiteID.SelectedValue, txtSiteName.Text, ddlSiteType.SelectedValue, txtNoBTS.Text, txtNoLinks.Text, txtLoadBand.Text, ddlEBAvailability.SelectedValue, txtEBPhase.Text, txtDGCapacity.Text, txtDGPhase.Text, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], user, DateTime.Now, "Nil", 1, txtDispatch.Text);

                }

            }
            lblSuccess.Visible = true;
            lblSuccess.Text = "Records Successfully Saved!";
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Duplicate Items has been entered, please correct it before proceeding or an entry for " + ddlSiteID.Text + " has already made, please go to edit page to make necessary changes!";
             Timer1.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
        }        

    }    
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    DropDownList ddlItem = (DropDownList)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItem");
                    Label txtUnit = (Label)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnit");
                    TextBox txtQty = (TextBox)gvItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQty");

                    //get the values from the TextBoxes
                    //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values
                    sc.Add(ddlItem.SelectedValue + "," + txtUnit.Text + "," + txtQty.Text);
                    if (sc.Contains(",,,"))
                    {
                        lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        lblErrorMessage.Text = "Fields should not be left empty!";
                        Timer1.Enabled = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string Quantity = txtQty.Text;
                        float num;
                        if (float.TryParse(Quantity, out num))
                        {
                            rowIndex++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Quantity field must be a number!";
                            Timer1.Enabled = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Call the method for executing inserts
                InsertRecords(sc);
                if (lblSuccess.Text == "Records Successfully Saved!")
                {
                    this.SetInitialRowToGrid();
                    string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;
                    StatusTableAdapters.tbl_NotificationsTableAdapter ds2;
                    ds2 = new StatusTableAdapters.tbl_NotificationsTableAdapter();

                    ds2.InsertNotification(ddlSiteID.SelectedValue, "BOM Notification", DateTime.Now, user, "Role6");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var main = (sender as DropDownList);

     foreach (GridViewRow row in gvItemList.Rows)
     {
           var ddl = (row.FindControl("ddlItem") as DropDownList);

           if (main.ClientID != ddl.ClientID && ddl.SelectedValue == main.SelectedValue)
           {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                string script = "alert('already selected!');";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), 
                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);
           }
     }         
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by .Items in foreach section?

Comment: Whats Id? In "main.Id != ddl.Id"

Comment: just wanted to make sure we are not comparing same dropdowns, we need to compare with others.

Comment: I tried but I'm still able to enter duplicate values in grid

Comment: debug step by step the code in asnwer and tell me what happens in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80647/discussion-between-jilu-and-mert).